# Is there any way to make relationship of neo4j in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, neo4j, relationship

I have created node with using `py2neo` package

```
from py2neo import Graph
from py2neo import Node
```

This is my pandas dataframe

[image: Pandas Dataframe]

I can create successfully node.

[image: Node Creation using pandas dataframe]

I have been trying to working with relationship getting error!

```
graph.create(Relationship(pmid, "Having_author", auth))
```

TypeError: Values of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> are not supported

I have also refer stack overflow question but still getting Error!

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738180/neo4j-create-nodes-and-relationships-from-pandas-dataframe-with-py2neo)

Is there any other way to create a relationship with pandas dataframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have convert series object in zip then it works for me

```
for pmid, au in tqdm(zip(data.PMID, data.AU),total = data.shape[0]):
    pmid_node = Node("pmid", name=int(pmid))
    au_node = Node("author", name=au)
    graph.create(Relationship(pmid_node, "HAVING_AUTHOR", au_node))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing because the ID for a node must be a literal (integer or string), but you set the ID as a Series when you wrote `...id = data['PMID'])` . It appears `py2neo` allowed you to create the node object with a faulty ID, but it really shouldn't, because all relationships with that node will fail since the ID is bad.

Recreate the Node Classes with an integer for the ID, and then the Relationship between them should be created without issues.

Note, I haven't tested this code, but this is how you would loop through a df and create nodes as you go.

```py
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    pmid = row['PMID'] #this is the integer PMID based on your df
    pmi_node = Node("PMID row " + str(i), id=pmid) #create node

    authid = row['AU'] #this is a string author name based on your df
    auth_node = Node("Auth row " + str(i), id=authid) #create node

    graph.create(pmi_node | auth_node)

    #create a relationship between the PMI and Auth for that row
    graph.create(Relationship(pmi_node , "Having_author", auth_node))
```

PS -- The SO link you referenced is not using the `py2neo` package, but is instead simply sending cypher code strings to the database using the `neo4j` python package. I'd recommend this route if you are a beginner.

Comment: I have try with code  pmid.astype(int) but still facing issue..........

Comment: TypeError: Unknown node type for 0       20301691
1       33237688
2       26903338
3       24741715
4       25299040
          ...   
4232    26065577
4233    26065544
4234    26065469
4235    26065462
4236    26065451
Name: PMID, Length: 4237, dtype: int32

Comment: It seems like you need to learn more about pandas data classes. you cannot convert a Series directly to an integer. what do you expect it to do, sum all the entries? concat? You need to make a node for each entry individually, not try to create a single node out of the entire series. I edited my answer with a sample code block.

Comment: you have written data.iterrows() but series object can't be iterate if you know it's throwing error..........

Comment: in your screenshot, data is a dataframe, not a series. if you've changed what `data` is in your code, please post an update.